# Frequent page allocation failures on a KVM

Tags: debian, memory, kvm-virtualization

Lately my server has been going down quite often. It happens almost every day early in the morning.

Looking at the syslog, I found a lot of these:

```
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359087] vballoon: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0x310da
```

Log files on the proxmox host node are clean. The machine itself  uses quite a bit of the resources, because of a web hosting platform running on it, but it has always been running smooth up until recently when those failures started occurring. Could you point me into right direction of dealing with this? Extended log:

```
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359087] vballoon: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0x310da
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359091] CPU: 1 PID: 282 Comm: vballoon Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359093] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.9.3-0-ge2fc41e-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359094]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81514281 00000000000310da ffff880525483c80
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359096]  ffffffff81144f9f 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000003
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359097]  0000000000000001 ffff88053ffebc00 ffffffff8115bde2 ffffffff81147a28
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359099] Call Trace:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359153]  [<ffffffff81514281>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359156]  [<ffffffff81144f9f>] ? warn_alloc_failed+0xdf/0x130
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359159]  [<ffffffff8115bde2>] ? next_online_pgdat+0x22/0x50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359173]  [<ffffffff81147a28>] ? drain_pages+0x28/0xa0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359175]  [<ffffffff8114930f>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8ef/0xb50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359178]  [<ffffffff8118894d>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x9d/0x150
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359180]  [<ffffffff81163408>] ? balloon_page_enqueue+0x18/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359222]  [<ffffffffa02f420a>] ? fill_balloon+0xaa/0x120 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359225]  [<ffffffffa02f4627>] ? balloon+0xc7/0x2a0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359228]  [<ffffffff810a9610>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359244]  [<ffffffffa02f4560>] ? update_balloon_stats+0xe0/0xe0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359246]  [<ffffffff8108954d>] ? kthread+0xbd/0xe0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359248]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359250]  [<ffffffff8151a3d8>] ? ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359252]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359266] Mem-Info:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359268] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359269] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359270] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359271] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359272] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359273] CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359274] CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359274] CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359275] CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359276] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359277] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359278] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359279] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359279] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359280] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359281] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359282] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359283] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359283] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359298] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359298] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359299] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359300] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359301] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359302] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359302] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359303] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306] active_anon:812442 inactive_anon:82788 isolated_anon:35
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306]  active_file:128202 inactive_file:128712 isolated_file:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306]  unevictable:0 dirty:2558 writeback:238 unstable:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306]  free:37909 slab_reclaimable:857614 slab_unreclaimable:37781
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306]  mapped:38913 shmem:102203 pagetables:10808 bounce:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359306]  free_cma:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359308] Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:52kB low:64kB high:76kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359311] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2980 20107 20107
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359313] Node 0 DMA32 free:78220kB min:10008kB low:12508kB high:15012kB active_anon:267444kB inactive_anon:77888kB active_file:209340kB inactive_file:206156kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129200kB managed:1437464kB mlocked:0kB dirty:4668kB writeback:192kB mapped:26648kB shmem:40348kB slab_reclaimable:556628kB slab_unreclaimable:22700kB kernel_stack:3648kB pagetables:6164kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359316] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 17126 17126
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359318] Node 0 Normal free:57508kB min:57520kB low:71900kB high:86280kB active_anon:2982324kB inactive_anon:253264kB active_file:303468kB inactive_file:308692kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):140kB isolated(file):0kB present:17825792kB managed:7022764kB mlocked:40kB dirty:5564kB writeback:760kB mapped:129004kB shmem:368464kB slab_reclaimable:2873828kB slab_unreclaimable:128424kB kernel_stack:2672kB pagetables:37068kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359321] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359322] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15908kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359329] Node 0 DMA32: 1960*4kB (UEM) 846*8kB (UEM) 455*16kB (UEM) 205*32kB (UEMR) 369*64kB (UEMR) 165*128kB (EMR) 15*256kB (MR) 2*512kB (M) 1*1024kB (R) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 79072kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359335] Node 0 Normal: 14518*4kB (UEM) 1*8kB (M) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 58080kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359341] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359341] 495355 total pagecache pages
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359342] 136152 pages in swap cache
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359344] Swap cache stats: add 1364729, delete 1228577, find 69817060/70012547
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359345] Free swap  = 1666868kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359345] Total swap = 3083260kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359346] 5242746 pages RAM
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359347] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359347] 2700757 pages reserved
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359348] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.359351] virtio_balloon virtio0: Out of puff! Can't get 1 pages
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562795] vballoon: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0x310da
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562799] CPU: 1 PID: 282 Comm: vballoon Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562800] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.9.3-0-ge2fc41e-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562801]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81514281 00000000000310da ffff880525483c80
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562803]  ffffffff81144f9f 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000003
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562804]  0000000000000001 ffff88053ffebc00 ffffffff8115bde2 ffffffff81147a28
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562805] Call Trace:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562809]  [<ffffffff81514281>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562812]  [<ffffffff81144f9f>] ? warn_alloc_failed+0xdf/0x130
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562813]  [<ffffffff8115bde2>] ? next_online_pgdat+0x22/0x50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562815]  [<ffffffff81147a28>] ? drain_pages+0x28/0xa0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562816]  [<ffffffff8114930f>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8ef/0xb50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562819]  [<ffffffff8118894d>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x9d/0x150
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562820]  [<ffffffff81163408>] ? balloon_page_enqueue+0x18/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562834]  [<ffffffffa02f420a>] ? fill_balloon+0xaa/0x120 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562837]  [<ffffffffa02f4627>] ? balloon+0xc7/0x2a0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562839]  [<ffffffff810a9610>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562841]  [<ffffffffa02f4560>] ? update_balloon_stats+0xe0/0xe0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562843]  [<ffffffff8108954d>] ? kthread+0xbd/0xe0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562844]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562846]  [<ffffffff8151a3d8>] ? ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562847]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562848] Mem-Info:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562849] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562850] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562851] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562851] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562852] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562852] CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562853] CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562853] CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562854] CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562854] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562855] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562856] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562856] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562857] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562857] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562857] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562858] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562858] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562859] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562859] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562860] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562860] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562861] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562861] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562862] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562863] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562863] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865] active_anon:812515 inactive_anon:82788 isolated_anon:35
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865]  active_file:128027 inactive_file:128588 isolated_file:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865]  unevictable:0 dirty:2558 writeback:238 unstable:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865]  free:37873 slab_reclaimable:857614 slab_unreclaimable:37781
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865]  mapped:38913 shmem:102203 pagetables:10808 bounce:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562865]  free_cma:0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562866] Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:52kB low:64kB high:76kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562868] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2980 20107 20107
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562870] Node 0 DMA32 free:78260kB min:10008kB low:12508kB high:15012kB active_anon:267444kB inactive_anon:77888kB active_file:208348kB inactive_file:206788kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129200kB managed:1437088kB mlocked:0kB dirty:4668kB writeback:192kB mapped:26648kB shmem:40348kB slab_reclaimable:556628kB slab_unreclaimable:22700kB kernel_stack:3648kB pagetables:6164kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562872] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 17126 17126
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562873] Node 0 Normal free:57324kB min:57520kB low:71900kB high:86280kB active_anon:2982616kB inactive_anon:253264kB active_file:303760kB inactive_file:307564kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):140kB isolated(file):0kB present:17825792kB managed:7021884kB mlocked:40kB dirty:5564kB writeback:760kB mapped:129004kB shmem:368464kB slab_reclaimable:2873828kB slab_unreclaimable:128424kB kernel_stack:2672kB pagetables:37068kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562875] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562876] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15908kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562881] Node 0 DMA32: 2033*4kB (UEM) 844*8kB (UEM) 455*16kB (UEM) 200*32kB (UEMR) 369*64kB (UEMR) 165*128kB (EMR) 15*256kB (MR) 2*512kB (M) 1*1024kB (R) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 79188kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562886] Node 0 Normal: 14592*4kB (UE) 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 58368kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562889] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562890] 495028 total pagecache pages
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562891] 136154 pages in swap cache
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562892] Swap cache stats: add 1364731, delete 1228577, find 69817060/70012548
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562892] Free swap  = 1666868kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562893] Total swap = 3083260kB
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562893] 5242746 pages RAM
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562894] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562894] 2700977 pages reserved
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562895] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.562897] virtio_balloon virtio0: Out of puff! Can't get 1 pages
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767216] vballoon: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0x310da
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767220] CPU: 1 PID: 282 Comm: vballoon Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767221] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.9.3-0-ge2fc41e-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767222]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81514281 00000000000310da ffff880525483c80
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767224]  ffffffff81144f9f 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000003
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767225]  0000000000000001 ffff88053ffebc00 ffffffff8115bde2 ffffffff81147a28
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767226] Call Trace:
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767230]  [<ffffffff81514281>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767233]  [<ffffffff81144f9f>] ? warn_alloc_failed+0xdf/0x130
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767235]  [<ffffffff8115bde2>] ? next_online_pgdat+0x22/0x50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767236]  [<ffffffff81147a28>] ? drain_pages+0x28/0xa0
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767237]  [<ffffffff8114930f>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8ef/0xb50
Oct 11 06:51:12 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767240]  [<ffffffff8118894d>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x9d/0x150
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767242]  [<ffffffff81163408>] ? balloon_page_enqueue+0x18/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767255]  [<ffffffffa02f420a>] ? fill_balloon+0xaa/0x120 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767257]  [<ffffffffa02f4627>] ? balloon+0xc7/0x2a0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767260]  [<ffffffff810a9610>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767262]  [<ffffffffa02f4560>] ? update_balloon_stats+0xe0/0xe0 [virtio_balloon]
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767264]  [<ffffffff8108954d>] ? kthread+0xbd/0xe0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767265]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767267]  [<ffffffff8151a3d8>] ? ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767269]  [<ffffffff81089490>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x180/0x180
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767270] Mem-Info:
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767270] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767272] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767272] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767273] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767273] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767274] CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767274] CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767275] CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767275] CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767275] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767276] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767277] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767277] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767278] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767278] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767279] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767279] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767280] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767294] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767294] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767295] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767295] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767296] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767296] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767297] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767297] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767298] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299] active_anon:812515 inactive_anon:82788 isolated_anon:35
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299]  active_file:127687 inactive_file:128518 isolated_file:0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299]  unevictable:0 dirty:2558 writeback:238 unstable:0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299]  free:37921 slab_reclaimable:857614 slab_unreclaimable:37781
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299]  mapped:38913 shmem:102203 pagetables:10808 bounce:0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767299]  free_cma:0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767301] Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:52kB low:64kB high:76kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767303] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2980 20107 20107
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767304] Node 0 DMA32 free:78296kB min:10008kB low:12508kB high:15012kB active_anon:267444kB inactive_anon:77888kB active_file:206988kB inactive_file:207104kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129200kB managed:1436088kB mlocked:0kB dirty:4668kB writeback:192kB mapped:26648kB shmem:40348kB slab_reclaimable:556628kB slab_unreclaimable:22700kB kernel_stack:3648kB pagetables:6164kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767307] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 17126 17126
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767308] Node 0 Normal free:57480kB min:57520kB low:71900kB high:86280kB active_anon:2982616kB inactive_anon:253264kB active_file:303760kB inactive_file:306968kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):140kB isolated(file):0kB present:17825792kB managed:7020756kB mlocked:40kB dirty:5564kB writeback:760kB mapped:129004kB shmem:368464kB slab_reclaimable:2873828kB slab_unreclaimable:128424kB kernel_stack:2672kB pagetables:37068kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767310] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767311] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15908kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767316] Node 0 DMA32: 2015*4kB (UEM) 863*8kB (UEM) 455*16kB (UEM) 199*32kB (UEMR) 369*64kB (UEMR) 165*128kB (EMR) 15*256kB (MR) 2*512kB (M) 1*1024kB (R) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 79236kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767320] Node 0 Normal: 14659*4kB (UE) 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 58636kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767324] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767324] 494792 total pagecache pages
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767325] 136155 pages in swap cache
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767326] Swap cache stats: add 1364732, delete 1228577, find 69817060/70012549
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767327] Free swap  = 1666868kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767327] Total swap = 3083260kB
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767328] 5242746 pages RAM
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767328] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767329] 2701259 pages reserved
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767329] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Oct 11 06:51:13 pleskvm kernel: [1895007.767331] virtio_balloon virtio0: Out of puff! Can't get 1 pages
```